# How to get the full source of a link using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I'm using selenium RC and want to get all the attributes and all. Something like:

```
link = sel.get_full_link('//a[@id="specific-link"]')
```

and the result would of:

```
print link
```

would be:

```
<a id="specific-link" name="links-name" href="url"> text </a>
```

Is this possible?

thanks

Comment: I don't see how this relates to XPath...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a fancier solution:

```
sel.get_eval("window.document.getElementByID('ID').innerHTML")
```

(don't be picky with me on the javascript..)

Comment: If there tag doesn't have ID, you can use something like this instead sel.getEval("this.browserbot.findElement('locator').innerHTML"); //where locator can be XPath, CSS, or by name/ID, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to do this would be to use the getHtmlSource command to get the entire HTML source, and then use either a regular expression or HTML parser to extract the element of interest.

The following Java example will output all links to System.out:

```
selenium.open("http://www.example.com/");
String htmlSource = selenium.getHtmlSource();
Pattern linkElementPattern = Pattern.compile("<a\\b[^>]*href=\"[^>]*>(.*?)</a>");
Matcher linkElementMatcher = linkElementPattern.matcher(htmlSource);
while (linkElementMatcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(linkElementMatcher.group());
}
```

Comment: ya, I thought of that. I was hoping selenium would offer a more elegant solution.

Comment: Unfortunately Selenium goes not have a way to do this itself.

Answer (score 1):

[getAttribute](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29)

String href = selenium.getAttribute("xpath=//a[@id="specific-link"]/@href")

Comment: Wish there was a way to mark answers as 'outdated' as the other answers are all incorrect now that getAttribute exists.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question because you can't get the *full source of an link* (or *element*) using `getAttribute`. See my answer for a method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to do just this, and came up with the following:-

var selenium = Selenium;

string linkText = selenium.GetText("//a[@href='/admin/design-management']");

Assert.AreEqual("Design Management", linkText);

Answer (score 0):

use below code to get all the links on the page:

```
$str3= "window.document.getElementsByTagName('a')";
$k = $this->selenium->getEval($str3);
$url = explode(",",$k);
$array_size = count($url);
$name=array();
$l=0;
for($i=0;$i<$array_size;$i++)
{
    if(!strstr($url[$i], 'javascript'))
    {
        $name[$l]=$url[$i];

        echo "\n".$name[$l];
        $l++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the link isn't dynamic, then try this rather cheesy, hacky solution (This is in Python):

```
selenium.click("//a[text()='Link Text']")<br>
selenium.wait_for_page_to_load(30000)<br>
myurl = selenium.get_location()
```

Cheesy but it works.

Note: this will not work if the link redirects.

Comment: I want to play around with the "source" of the link. Like see that the name is so and so and that there is no `<b>` tags inside the link data.. that sort of stuff. What you're suggesting will only give me the url which I can get: `selenium.get_attribute("//a[text()='Link Text']/@href")`